# using jquery selectors within google map does not work

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm using jquery and googlemaps (gmap2). I am finding issues with using the jquery selectors for class divs on the map. When I try to select the div (both ID and classes) I get a null return. I am guessing there's some kind of conflict with the JS google maps. To verify that my jquery is correct, I have tried to select tags and different id/classes, that works.

Can anyone suggest what is the cause or work around?

I am using jq 1.3.2

Comment: It would be helpful if you could isolate the example as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out someone had redefined $ as another function and used noconflict

Answer (score 0):

I've used jquery mixed with google maps with no issues. Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps doesn't like the array of objects jquery's selector engine returns. similarly jquery doesn't seem to like document.getElementById's raw output, so you'd need to do..

```
var el = document.getElementById("your-element");
var jQel = $(el);
```

..you can then pass el to the google maps API and jQel to jQuery. Although obviously if you can avoid using jQuery at all your code will be more efficient.

Comment: If you're required to use the first line, I don't understand the point of the second line... just use `el` in both.

Comment: Since he was using jQuery i'd assume he was actually doing something to the element with jQuery elsewhere in the code, rather than just randomly using the selector engine! 


Then again this was a little over three years ago so i doubt we'll ever find out what he was upto ;)